# Could not install python3.5-pip

Tags: python3, pip

I am trying to install pip over python3.5 and my Ubuntu 16.04 does not want to perform it. I am executing the command `sudo apt-get install python3.5-pip` and then I get result like:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.5-pip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.5-pip'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.5-pip'
```

Comment: There is no `python3.5-pip`. There's only [`python3-pip`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/python3-pip).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answer in the thread below, `pip` should be already installed as you are using Python 3.4+

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3

In case you don't have it installed, try running the command below

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: thank you! I believe it is a valid system respond, after I applied `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`:`taras@taras-5:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).`